# BSONVersionError: Unsupported BSON version, bson types must be from bson 5.x.x in Node.js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Description:**
I'm encountering a `BSONVersionError` in my Node.js application, and the error message states "Unsupported BSON version, bson types must be from bson 5.x.x." I believe this is related to the MongoDB Node.js driver or another library using BSON.

**Details:**

- I've checked my dependencies, and I'm using MongoDB Node.js driver version [your version].
- I've already attempted to update the MongoDB Node.js driver to version 5.x.x using `npm install mongodb@5.x.x`.
- I'm running my application against MongoDB server version 5.9.2

**Code Snippets:**
dbClientObj.collection(CollectionName).findOne({_id:_id: new ObjectId(employeeId),

**Error Stack Trace:**
BSONVersionError: Unsupported BSON version, bson types must be from bson 5.x.x
at serializeInto (D:\beyond-carts\PhoenixMind\SubscriptionService\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\lib\bson.cjs:3670:23)
rvice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\commands.js:377:37)
at Msg.toBin (D:\beyond-carts\PhoenixMind\SubscriptionService\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\commands.js:366:29)
at MessageStream.writeCommand (D:\beyond-carts\PhoenixMind\SubscriptionService\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:43:34)
at write (D:\beyond-carts\PhoenixMind\SubscriptionService\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:479:30)
at Connection.command (D:\beyond-carts\PhoenixMind\SubscriptionService\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:312:13)

**Environment:**

- Node.js version: 18
- MongoDB server version: 5.9.2

**What I've Tried:**
I have tired using bson package like new BSON.ObjectId(<employee_id>)

**Question:**
How can I resolve the `BSONVersionError` and make sure my application is using BSON types from version 5.x.x?

Comment: Please edit your question.  The code snippet is not a valid js, the log is missing a part in the middle, and is likely not related to the code snippet. Well, at least not to the `new ObjectId` part as the question implies. Also add content of `(D:\beyond-carts\PhoenixMind\SubscriptionService\node_modules\mongodb\package.json`  to confirm "your version". The `driver version [your version].` part of the question doesn't say anything useful, only shows lack of attention / efforts  to make the question answerable.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in one of my Node.js applications after upgrading mongodb/mongoose packages.

The solution to my specific error was rather simple although the error message did not show any hint as also discovered by you.

After looking into the code I quickly realized it was due to use of

```
new ObjectId(...)
```

in my aggregation pipelines.

I imported ObjectId from mongodb package. That was the problem in new mongoose version: Had to import ObjectId from mongoose instead like so:

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose'
...
... new Types.ObjectId(...)
```

Maybe that helps someone if not you!

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue while using connect-mongodb-session in my project, receiving an error message stating, "Unsupported BSON version, bson types must be from bson 5.x.x at E:\Web Development\Classes\Practice\authCheck\node_modules\connect-mongodb-session\index.js:224:19 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)".

Although my previous project, which utilized the same dependencies, was functioning correctly, I identified the problem by comparing the configurations of the two projects. In the previous project, I had connect-mongodb-session version ^3.1.1, whereas the current project, exhibiting the error, was using version ^4...

**To resolve the issue, I opted to downgrade the connect-mongodb-session version to 3.1.1. Following this adjustment, the project operated without errors.** It seems that the latest version of connect-mongodb-session may not be compatible when handling BSON types.